# How do I debug a Python-C++ mixed project with gdb attach process and catch throw?

Tags: python, c++, gdb

I am having a mixed Python & C++ project and using the following steps to debug:

- start Python process
- use `ps ax | grep python` to identify the process debugging process that will be attached to
- start the gdb attach process
  The "gdb process" in VSCode has following configuration, that basically only wants `std::vector` error to be stopped, with the pattern described in gdb doc: `catch throw <exception-regex>`

```json
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "program": "/opt/conda/bin/python", /* My virtual env */
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [            
            {
                "description": "Enable all-exceptions",
                "text": "catch throw std::vector*",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
    }
```

However, it stopped at one point (not the `std::vector` expected) with debug log

```
Thread 1 "python" hit Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0xff0e650, tinfo=0x7f8f21433560 <typeinfo for torch::TypeError>, dest=0x7f8f209440f0 <torch::TypeError::~TypeError()>) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:80
```

and the VSCode debugger stopped, but could not really target to the error code line; the status was somehow like
[image: error screenshot]

So..

- Why did it stop abruptly?
- How can one trace the error stack?

PS:
I have `RuntimeError: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)` thrown by Python process but I can not target the culprit line in C++ code. I want to filter this error out.

Comment: I have some questions : why would you even throw an exception of type `std::vector*` (that is very unusual)? Or do you actually throw some other exception type e.g. std::exception/std::runtime_error?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I have `RuntimeError: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)` thrown by Python process but I can not target the culprit line in C++ code

Comment: Do you have unit tests for your C++ code? Because that's where I would start, make sure you test your C++ code from C++ unit tests. One of the tests should try to reproduce the python input and then fail too. You can then debug the unit test executable fairly easy.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's a big project, all existing UT could pass. It's a real scenario case and the only way I could figure out is to target the line which raises the exception

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think it's a proper and general scenario that we want to just stop at the line in our project which raises the exception

Comment: From GDB's point of view, it's operating on the python executable with a number of shared objects, including scipy, pytorch, libstdc++, and objects from your project. GDB can look at the call stack when an exception is caught. Can you tell us what distinguishes the particular std::vector exception you're interested in from any other std::vector exception? Is there a function or functions GDB can look for in the call stack?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks for your insightful answer, I updated the purpose in the description PS